# Having trouble uninstalling an app

Tags: software-installation

Im trying to uninstall claws-mail from my x1 carbon on ubuntu 18.04.
I've tried uninstalling from the software centre and also using command line but the app is still there and my emails are still in it.
I'm a total newbie to linux and want to keep my os light with no unneccesary programs.
Thanks

Comment: Exactly what commands did you try, and what was the result? Please show us full output when possible. You may not understand the output yet, but we do.

Comment: it was just a sudo apt uninstall command which didn't work. ive gotten rid of it with synaptics package manager now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to see in the Synaptic package manager if some dependencie of the program continues installes(something like "claws-mail-acpi-notifier") and try to unistall it from there.
Also you can delete completely programs from synaptic.